# Error trying to delete S3 directory (and contents) in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5, storage

I'm trying to delete and entire directory with any preceding folders or contents. I can delete upload, create and delete single files but get errors when deleting the master folder:

Folders start with the `Auth::user` id, so I was hoping to delete the master folder when deleting the user.

First option: `Storage::disk('s3')->deleteDirectory(Auth::id());`
Error: "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"
Readout: https://gist.github.com/jackbarham/14fce68b51abe4eaadd2

Second option: `Storage::deleteDirectory(Auth::id());`
Error: "Call to a member function delete() on integer"
Readout: https://gist.github.com/jackbarham/32dc6dc6c3d7f1b3c636

I've been using `Storage::disk('s3')->delete($path . $filename);` for adding and removing individual files without any issues.

I'm using AWS SDK V3 (as per Laravel docs)

Comment: Can you share the stack traces from either or both of the errors you're receiving? Are you using Amazon SDK V2 or V3?

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my questions with full error readouts, and i'm using V3

Comment: Are you using Clockwork by any chance?

Comment: No I'm not using Clockwork

Comment: The "Call to a member function delete() on integer" error for your second option [appears to be from your controller](https://gist.github.com/jackbarham/32dc6dc6c3d7f1b3c636#file-gistfile1-txt-L5), likely unrelated to deleting a file through the Storage facade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)**

> First option: Storage::disk('s3')->deleteDirectory(Auth::id()); Error: "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"

This one is tricky, as the problem may not be necessarily caused by your code. Had this error once and in my case the server hosting an API I was calling had load issues. The calls could not be efficiently handled, hence the error on my side.

In this case you could try increasing `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in **php.ini** from `100` to `200` - and retry. More about the property **[here](http://xdebug.org/docs/basic)**.

**(2)**

> Second option: Storage::deleteDirectory(Auth::id()); Error: "Call to a member function delete() on integer"

This one seems more obvious. `deleteDirectory()` takes a string as first parameter, while `Auth::id()` gives you integer. Cast it to the correct type: `(string)Auth::id()`.

Anyway, hopefully changing `xdebug.max_nesting_level` value will do the job.

Comment: I've already offered the second solution you've given to him on the laravel subreddit and it didn't solve the problem.